# Transform multiple columns the tidy way

Tags: r, tidyverse

I wonder whether there is a solution for transforming multiple columns within a pipe.

Lets say we have a tibble with three columns. `iq_pre` and `iq_post` have to be transormend on log scale and be saved into new columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble(
  iq_pre = rnorm(10, 100, 15),
  iq_post = rnorm(10, 100, 18),
  gender = rep(c("m", "f"), each = 5)
)
```

I know I could get the result with base R by doing

```
df[c("iq_pre_lg", "iq_post_lg")] <- log(df[c("iq_pre", "iq_post")])
```

or looping over the columns with lapply.

The only tidy solution I came up with is to use mutate manually for each column like this

```
df %<>% 
  mutate(iq_pre_lg = log(iq_pre),
         iq_post_lg = log(iq_post))
```

Since the names of the columns which should be transformed start with the same letters, I could also use

```
df %<>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("iq")), funs(lg = log(.)))
```

But what if I want to convert like 20 columns with different names? Is there a way to use `purrr::map` or maybe even `tidyr::nest` to solve this in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
df %>%
     mutate_at(vars(matches("iq")), log)
```

One advantage with `matches` is that it can take multiple patterns to be matched in a single call.  For e.g., if we need to apply the function on columns that start (`^`) with 'iq' or  (`|`) those end (`$`) with 'oq', this can be passed into the single `matches`

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches('^iq|oq$'), log)
```

---

If the column names are completely different and there are `n` patterns for the `n` column, but if there is still some order in the position of columns, then the column position numbers can be passed into the `vars`.  In the current example, the 'iq' columns are the 1st and 2nd columns

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(1:2, log)
```

Similarly, if the 20 columns occupy the 1st 20 positions

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(1:20, log)
```

Or if the positions are 1 to 6, 8 to 12, 41:50

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(1:6, 8:12, 41:50), log)
```